# Save Attribute Query

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, query, select-by-attribute

How to save attribute query on qgis 2.14? I have more than 20 queries. The recent queries save only 20 queries. If I can save them, it will be more effiecient.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is yet a way to save query in QGIS.

You could of course use any text editor and copy/paste your query but that's not very practical.

that being said, one workaround could be to use rule based symbology (one rule by query), this way you could choose to display only the feature that match your query and also by selecting "Show Features Visible On Map" in the attribute table to see only the attribute of feature that match your query.

Depending on what your purpose is this could be usefull. (at last your query are stored in the QGIS document and you still could edit your data. Also there is no problem if a feature is selected by several query)

Comment: Similar to saving them in a text tile, you could save queries in a text box in a print composer. That way they're at least stored in the QGIS project.